# Recreate initial Entity Framework Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I use Entity Framework Code First Migrations. In my project are already a lot of migrations but not the initial one. I have a dev database with an entry of the initial migration.
My question is, is there a way to recreate the initial migration cs-file to for example create another dev database.

Comment: Are you saying you inadvertently deleted a migration or something else? Should not really matter. If you point your connection string to a new database it should get created and match your current model. Another option, if you only have a single DEV database you could just [reset migrations](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate).

Comment: Unfortunately it is already in production. I want to setup a new testenvironment by just changing the connectionstring. The database could not be created because one (or more) of the C# migrationfiles are lost. So the update-database command wants to alter colums of tables never created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force migrations to create your database from scratch:

```
Update-Database -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase
```

This will cause all database objects to be created and the migrations to be applied. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Another way to do this is with [initializers](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx). You could temporarily change it to use say `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`. What we do is test for the DEV environment via a web.config setting and use that initializer in DEV otherwise use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` or `NullDatabaseInitializer` in PROD.